# How to avoid XML Injection when using WriteElementString

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code and throws  an XML injection(Please see the highlighted text) .can some let me know how this can be removed

```
private string GetRecordSet(OleDbDataReader oDR)
        {
            XmlTextWriter xTWriter = null;
            StringWriter oSWriter = null;
            int iRecCnt=0;
            string sName = String.Empty;
            string sValue = String.Empty;

            try
            {
                //Create Out XML    
                oSWriter = new StringWriter();
                xTWriter = new XmlTextWriter(oSWriter);
                xTWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                xTWriter.WriteStartElement("SESSION");

                while(oDR.Read()) 
                {
                    iRecCnt++;

                    sName = oDR.GetValue(0).ToString();
                    sValue = oDR.GetValue(1).ToString();
                    **xTWriter.WriteElementString(sName, sValue);**
                }

                xTWriter.WriteElementString("TotalRecords", iRecCnt.ToString());
                xTWriter.WriteEndElement(); //ROWSET END

                //Return XML string. If no records found then return empty string
                string sRtrn = oSWriter.ToString();
                if (iRecCnt == 0) sRtrn = string.Empty;
                return sRtrn;
            }
```

Comment: `throws an XML injection` What throws it?

Comment: When I am running my tool it says xml injection found.In the while loop for writeElementString.

Comment: "your tool". OK i see. :)

Comment: The name of the tool is Fortify

Answer (score 1):

You're not sanitizing input in any way.  Its XML Injectionable because of the XML metacharacters that can be used to change your code into a behavior that is unintended.  Examples of the metacharacters:  single quote, double quote, <, > - anything that when put through your code could actually cause the code to write xml elements or attributes that are unintended.

Comment: +1, and I just want to add the changing highlighted string to `xTWriter.WriteElementString(sName, System.SecurityElement.Escape(sValue));` should help.